# Match content in a table with Perl

Tags: regex, perl, switch-statement

I'm using a [HTML::Query](http://search.cpan.org/~kamelkev/HTML-Query-0.07/lib/HTML/Query.pm) to pull the content out from each td tag. I do want it in html format. Now when I print it, it seems to print the class one twice, most of the time. Any thoughts what's going on here?
Here is the code I'm using:

```
for my $td ($doc->query("td")) {
$td= $td->as_HTML;
  given($td){
  when (/class=\"class1\">(.*?)<\/td>/){
          my $output = $1;
     print "$output\n";
     }

  when (/class=\"class2\">(.*?)<\/td>/){
          my $output = $1;
     print "$output\n";
     }
  when (/class=\"class3\">(.*?)<\/td>/){
          my $output = $1;
     print "$output\n";
     }
  when (/class=\"class4\">(.*?)<\/td>/){
          my $output = $1;
     print "$output\n";
     }
  }


Input:
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="class1">question</td>
  <td class="class2">No response</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="class1">question</td>
  <td class="class2">No response</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="class3">Answer</td>
  <td class="class4">Answer is available</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `query` returns all the `<td>` elements; there are two of them with `class="class1"`, so that's why that case matches twice.

Since you've asked about printing the contents of each *row* on a single line, give the following a try. Notice that I'm using some methods from `HTML::Element` instead of trying to match raw HTML code.

```
for my $tr ($doc->query("tr")) {
  my ($td1, $td2) = $tr->contents_list();
  # Print contents of $td1 and $td2 on the same line
}
```

Comment: Thanks. how do i get it to display once with something like: question No reponse question No reponse Answer Answer is available all on each new row?

Comment: I'm not sure; I've never used HTML::Query before. Skimming the docs, I think you'll need to run a query to get each <tr> element instead, and then for each of those, process the child <td> elements.

Comment: OK, I will try that. I was able to get the content I need without using HTML::Query and just by using the given()/when statements. It feels like I was complicating the issue.Thanks for trying :)